# Rust: Rc<Foo> にトレイト std::op::Add を実装させたい

Tags: rust

オペレータオーバーロードしたいです。単純な `Struct` ならいいのですが、 `Rc<Struct>` に `std::op::Add` を実装させようとすると、コンパイルできません。解決策はあるでしょうか。

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::ops::Add;

struct Struct;

// コンパイルできない
impl Add for Rc<Struct> {
    type Output = Rc<Struct>;
    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Rc::new(Struct{})
    }
}

// コンパイルできる
impl Add for Struct {
    type Output = Struct;
    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Struct{}
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

コンパイルエラーのメッセージは以下です。

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
  = note: the impl does not reference any types defined in this crate
  = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

Comment: 回答ではないのでコメントで補足しますが、この種のimplが認められなくなったのはRFC 1023 https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md による意図的な変更のようです。正確なorphan規則もここに書いてあります。

Comment: リンクありがとうございます。面白そうなので時間があるときに読んでみますー

Answer (score 7, accepted):

traitを実装する場合、型かtraitのどちらかが定義されているcrateである必要があるため、`Rc<Struct>`に`Add`を実装することは直接はできません。
(なお、`impl Add<Struct> for Rc<Struct> {...}`のようなことは出来る）

よく行う代替手段としては、いわゆる[newtype pattern](https://github.com/rust-unofficial/patterns/blob/master/patterns/newtype.md)と呼ばれる方法で、

```
struct RcStruct(Rc<Struct>);
```

のように型を新しく定義してその型に対して`Add`を実装します。このままだと`RcStruct`は`Rc`の関連関数を使えないので、`Deref`と`DerefMut`を実装しておきます。

```
impl Deref for RcStruct {
    type Target = Rc<Struct>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}
```

(`DerefMut`は略)加えて`Into`か`From`を実装しておくと`Rc::new(...).into()`で`RcStruct`を生成できます。

```
impl Into<RcStruct> for Rc<Struct> {
    fn into(self) -> RcStruct {
        RcStruct(self)
    }
}
```

これで以下のように`Add`を実装します。

```
impl Add for RcStruct {
    type Output = RcStruct;
    fn add(self, _rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Rc::new(Struct {}).into()
    }
}
```

Comment: なるほど newtype + Deref ですか... パターンとして覚えておくのがいいですね。あと `.into()` で生成するのもスッキリしてていいですねぇ